# Is there a better way to make a chessboard in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

Hey I am new to javascript. I have just started reading Eloquent Javascript by Marin Haverbeke and I finished the chessboard problem in chapter 2 but I was wondering if my solution is good enough. I tried making the chessboard with nested loops but I am not very familiar with Javascript so I decided to only use one loop. I believe it is a faster solution because it runs in O(n) time where n is the size of the n x n board.

```js
const boardSize = 8;
for (let i = 0; i < boardSize / 2; i++) {
  console.log(" #".repeat(boardSize / 2));
  console.log("# ".repeat(boardSize / 2));
}
```

You can change the boardSize so it will work for any size board.
Output looks something like this:

```
 # # # #
# # # # 
 # # # #
# # # # 
 # # # #
# # # # 
 # # # #
# # # #
```

Please let me know if this is cheating or if it is an acceptable solution. All advice is apprenciated :)

Comment: Looks good to me

Comment: Chessboards have 64 squares, not 64 million.  Big O is irrelevant.

Comment: *You* wrote a single `for` loop, but `repeat` may *also* be a loop (there are a number of ways it could be implemented). This problem isn't necessary to optimize, but the bottom line is that if it solves the problem, and doesn't cause other different problems, it's "right".

Comment: Two loops need `m * m = 8 * 8` steps and one loop needs `n = 64 = 8 * 8 = m * m` steps. Both approaches have time complexity `O(1)`, because `m` and `n` are fixed, not variable. For dynamic sizes both approaches have time complexity `O(m * m) = O(n)`.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution is perfectly acceptable.

You could also aim to call `console.log` only once, and avoid even that remaining `for` loop:

```js
const boardSize = 8;
const row = " #".repeat(boardSize / 2);
const doublerow = row + "\n" + row.slice(1) + " \n";
console.log(doublerow.repeat(boardSize / 2).slice(0, -1));
```

Unless `boardsize` could have any value, the time complexity is irrelevant. But if larger sizes are allowed, then your solution is still O(n²) since that is the amount of characters it outputs. Specifically, the `repeat` method does not run in constant time if the argument is variable.

Answer (score 0):

A chessboard has 64 squares. How about only one console.log

```js
const boardSize = 4;
const board = [];
for (let i = 0; i < boardSize; i++) {
  board.push("⬛⬜".repeat(boardSize));
  board.push("⬜⬛".repeat(boardSize));
}
console.log(board.join("\n"))
```